# Establish a file index without using Lucene

Tags: java, indexing

I am just want to build a small index file system (with over 3000 text files and beyond 5 GB).I have already searched results form Google or something else but did not get what I wants.All of the results are related to Lucene,however I just want to do it without any third libraries,will you give me some advice or some examples?

Comment: If you use a DB, you can do something like a tag-based implementation (a many-to-many relation between documents and tags). Unfortunately, you then have to do all the work e.g. lucene does (like NLP) to get good results. Why don't you want to use a 3rd party lib?

Comment: Its a huge topic, and one which is hard to answer succinctly. A decent answer would be too big for a Q&A site like this. Instead you should read around the topic of indexing and searching. Look how well known indexes work, or maybe read the wiki article on search indexing http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Search_engine_indexing. It would be much, much easier for you to use an exising 3rd party library than to reinvent the wheel.

Comment: We are not to use a 3rd party lib.And I just want to build a small one.Just split the key words and then use an inverted index,finally can provide a search.Would you guys give me some example?

Answer (score 0):

An extremely basic solution might be to use an inverted index. This is where you read all the documents to be indexed and store the words found as keys in a map, with the value being a list of the documents that contain those words.

doc 1;

> this is an example document

doc 2;

> this document is number two

your map would have;

```
this -> doc1, doc2
is -> doc1, doc2
an -> doc1
example -> doc1
document -> doc1, doc2
number -> doc2
two -> doc2
```

Comment: what you said is just I want to do,but I do not know how to realize that.Do you have some relevant example?